# how to attach a running node.js process and debug WITHOUT a GUI?

Tags: node.js, debugging, console

By sending SIGUSR1 I can start internal debugger on port 5858, and can use node-inspect to debug the running process via GUI in browser.

However if the host server have NO GUI, and this kind of port(5858) is firewalled due to security policy. How can I debug it in local console? like using gdb in C/C++?

I tried telnet 5858 locally but it seems to talk in HTTP for debugging operations. Is there any existing tool to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js (up to at least version 7.x.x) has a built-in CLI/text client for the debugger. To access it, start your program with a `debug` argument; for example: `node debug server.js`.

For details on how to navigate the debugger, [refer to the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

The documentation includes an explanation of how to attach to a running PID (`node debug -p <pid>`) or how to attach to the process via port 5858 like you are asking about (`node debug localhost:5858`).

As of this writing, Node.js version 8.0.0 has not been released yet. However, it is possible that the CLI debugger will be replaced in that version. (Just putting this here for people who find this answer in the future. If Node.js version 8.0.0 or later has changed from 7.x.x such that this answer is no longer valid, consider adding the correct information for the newer version right here. :-D )

Comment: if using 'node debug server.js', the process will be paused and ready for debugging. But what I need is to start the process normally, and if there are something wrong during runtime, I can attach to it and do a console debugging instead of browser GUI.

Comment: Type `cont` at the debug prompt and the program will run until it hits a break point. Or use `node debug -p <PID>` to connect to a particular PID. Or use `node debug localhost:5858` to connect to port 5858 with the debugger.